# Implementation of Generic SQL Data Reader

Tags: c#, generics

I am using below virtual method to read the data from SQL Data Reader like:

```
public IList<District> GetList()
{
    IList<District> _list = new List<District>();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
    try
    {
        string StoreProcedure = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SP"].ToString();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoreProcedure, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        _list = new GenericReader<District>().CreateList(rdr);
        rdr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        IsConnectionOpenThenClose(con);
    }
    return _list;
}
```

District Class:

```
public class District
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And GenericReader Class as:

```
public class GenericReader<T>
{
    public virtual List<T> CreateList(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        var results = new List<T>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var item = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(property.Name)))
                {
                    Type convertTo = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType;
                    property.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(reader[property.Name], convertTo), null);
                }
            }
            results.Add(item);
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Is this approach is better or still, we can refactor?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. If you're still open for suggestions, why did you already accept an answer? It's a feature of StackExchange that now question every "closes" completely (unless it's on hold), you don't need to point that out to other users.

Comment: Understood! will remove the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetList()`

- `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all implementing the `IDisposable` interface hence you should either call `Dispose()`  on that objects or enclosing them in a `using` block.
- You should use `var` instead of the concrete type if the right-hand-side of an assignment makes the concrete type obvious.
  E.g the line `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);` we can see at first glance that the concrete type   is `SqlConnection` and therfor we should use `var con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);` instead.
- Using abbreviations for naming things shouldn't be done because it makes reading and maintaining the code so much harder.
- Underscore-prefixed variablenames are usually used for class-level variables. Method-scoped variables should be named using `camelCase` casing hence `list` would be better than `_list` because Sam the maintainer wouldn't wonder about it.
- You return an `IList<>` which is good because coding against interfaces is the way to go.

Comment: Would like to read more! Mostly about `CreateList()`!

Comment: Do I need to call `con.Close()` and `con.Dispose()` both methods? or `Dispose()` will do the work of `.Close()`?

Comment: Dispose is doing the Close for you.

Comment: Can you please explain Point no2?

Comment: Edited answer for No2

Comment: yes got it! any benefit of doing this?

Comment: Its less typing and easier to refactor.